ImportError: libc10_cuda.so Heeelp
When I was fine-tuning LLM, the following error occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./graphedit/train/train_lora.py", line 45, in <module>
    from llama_flash_attn_monkey_patch import (
  File "/root/mogai2/GraphEdit/LLM/graphedit/train/llama_flash_attn_monkey_patch.py", line 9, in <module>
    from flash_attn.flash_attn_interface import flash_attn_unpadded_qkvpacked_func
  File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flash_attn/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from flash_attn.flash_attn_interface import (
  File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flash_attn/flash_attn_interface.py", line 8, in <module>
    import flash_attn_2_cuda as flash_attn_cuda
ImportError: libc10_cuda.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I followed this solution.
And my cuda is as follows:
bin  cuda  cuda-11  cuda-11.3  etc  games  include  lib  man  sbin  share  src

But get:
/sbin/ldconfig.real: File /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-egl-gbm.so.1 is empty, not checked.
/sbin/ldconfig.real: File /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-egl-gbm.so.1.1.0 is empty, not checked.

Is there any possible solution?

libc10_cuda is a PyTorch internal component. It has nothing directly to do with the CUDA tool kit or runtime
